Suddenly I am getting the following Excel message on a couple of different files: "Sorry, we couldn't find"
Suddenly I am getting the following Excel message on a couple of different files:

Sorry, we couldn't find /Users/cepw/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/_3a Rowing/_CRC Rowing/_CRC Treasurer/_CRC QuickBooks & Wix/CRC Shell Inventory/CRC Club Owned Boats 07:CRC Club Owned Boats 07:24.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

I think the problem is the the use of / in a date sequence. Changed / to -, now it seems to work.
Is that the real solution or is there something else I should be aware of?

Where are you getting this error? Is this in a spreadsheet that is referring to other sheets to import data? Your question needs a lot more information before it will make sense. Please EDIT your question and add this information.

The total length of your path is currently 192 characters. All office programs adhere to the (old windows standard) maximum path length of 255 characters. You might run into issues if you go beyond that.


Changed / to -, now it seems to work.
Is that the real solution or is there something else I should be aware of?

If the error isn't appearing any more, then yes, that's the best solution.
As an aside, it's generally best to avoid using forward slashes (/) in the names of files. The way macOS and other UNIXes handle file locations (aka paths) is by using the slash character to separate directories (folders) from their contents. Technically, these slash characters in names can be escaped as a literal / in a file/directory name, but this often creates strange issues as you've seen. Using those slashes appears to have tricked Excel into trying to find a file named 24.xlsx inside the CRC Club Owned Boats 07 folder, assuming the file was literally named CRC Club Owned Boats 07/24.xlsx.
Dashes are safe characters, and I always use dashes when a filename needs to contain a date.

Both / and : should be avoided in file names on macOS.
Historically, : was the directory separator on older Mac operating systems, and / the separator on Unix - which means that regular files could use the other character in file names, and this had to be supported as well. This answer has more technical detail.
The end result is that some applications will see a / in the filename, while others will see a : - and when they pass information about filenames to each other, confusion like this will happen.
